# Python: pass a function call's list index as its own argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-efficiency

I've got a rather sizable (3.9 kB) script that's designed to align some text based on some parameters, centering, etc.
Here are the blocks I'm looking to improve: **(Apologies for the somewhat-codegolf but the point is not what the functions do but their structure: they work fine as it is in theory but I ache to make them shorter)**

```
    #manage + control the margin in spaces between the body text and right vertical rule
def calcMgn(lnNum): return toEven(bwinner-(len(LnOpn[lnNum])+len(LnCtn[lnNum])),-1)//2
def calcRMgn(lnNum): return (0-(1-(toEven(((bwinner-(len(LnOpn[lnNum])+len(LnCtn[lnNum])))//2),-1))))
def calcLenOf(lnNum): return len(LnMgn[lnNum])+len(LnOpn[lnNum])+len(LnCtn[lnNum])+calcRMgn(lnNum)
def calcRDiff(lnNum): return LnMgnR[lnNum] - (lenOf[lnNum] - bwinner)
def calcRMgnSpa(lnNum): return ((LnMgnRAdjust[lnNum])-adjust)
    #there absolutely must be a better way to call a function based on its position in a list than the following:
LnMgn=[calcMgn(0)*spa,calcMgn(1)*spa,calcMgn(2)*spa,calcMgn(3)*spa]
LnMgnR=[calcRMgn(0),calcRMgn(1),calcRMgn(2),calcRMgn(3)]
lenOf=[calcLenOf(0),calcLenOf(1),calcLenOf(2),calcLenOf(3)]
LnMgnRAdjust=[calcRDiff(0),calcRDiff(1),calcRDiff(2),calcRDiff(3)]
LnMgnR_spa=[calcRMgnSpa(0)*spa,calcRMgnSpa(1)*spa,calcRMgnSpa(2)*spa,calcRMgnSpa(3)*spa,]
    #take the lengths for a test drive to see if they break any rules
testLen=[LnMgn[0] + LnOpn[0] + spa + LnCtn[0] + LnMgnR_spa[0],\
LnMgn[1] + LnOpn[1] + spa + LnCtn[1] + LnMgnR_spa[1],\
LnMgn[2] + LnOpn[2] + spa + LnCtn[2] + LnMgnR_spa[2],\
LnMgn[3] + LnOpn[3] + spa + LnCtn[3] + LnMgnR_spa[3]] #instead of this, I want something like a for statement or ???
for i in range(0,3):
    if len(testLen[i]) > bwinner:
        LnMgnR_spa[i] = int((toEven(LnMgnRAdjust[i])-adjust)-(len(testLen[i])-bwinner))*str(spa)
    #concatenate strings
addLine=[idt + vl + LnMgn[0] + LnOpn[0] + spa + LnCtn[0] + LnMgnR_spa[0] + vr + nl,\
idt + vl + LnMgn[1] + LnOpn[1] + spa + LnCtn[1] + LnMgnR_spa[1] + vr + nl,\
idt + vl + LnMgn[2] + LnOpn[2] + spa + LnCtn[2] + LnMgnR_spa[2] + vr + nl,\
idt + vl + LnMgn[3] + LnOpn[3] + spa + LnCtn[3] + LnMgnR_spa[3] + vr + nl]
```

I know SO's policy of "we won't write your code for you" and I definitely don't intend to ask for such favours, just guidance: **is there a way (and I have googled, and googled) to make LnMgn and its similar arrays more efficient and less huge by its contents dynamically iteravely calling and self-defining based on their array index?**

Comment: Don't just apologise for bad formatting - if you want other people to read and follow your code, you should read and follow [the style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You should read up on e.g. `map` and `zip` as well as *"comprehensions"* to help improve your code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe good thing nobody else will ever read this, then

Comment: ...except that **you're asking all of us to read it now**. You can write your own code however you like, but only if you never ask a question, or otherwise collaborate with anybody else. As soon as that's not the case (or before, as the case may change...), find and follow a style guide; it's just basic courtesy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create a list of functions:

```
func_list = [f1, f2, f3, f4]
```

and call them, for example, like:

```
[func_list[i](i) for i in range(4)]
```

This example would return:

```
[f1(0), f2(1), f3(2), f4(3)]
```

Comment: You could also do `[func(index) for index, func in enumerate(func_list)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list comprehension. One example:

```
LnMgn = [calcMgn(index)*spa for index in range(4)]
```

You can do the same for all the others.

Comment: Also, just want to say reading this stuff makes my eyes bleed. Please format your code properly, it's better for everyone.